# I want to show error message when textbox is null in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a control input type is text that will accept id which will enter by user. When user doesn't enter any id and when he will click on button for getting details I have to show message that "please enter id in textbox". All these things has beeen design in mvc3. Now please help to us that how we will do it ? I am new on mvc3.

**Update**

This is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="centerize">
   <input type="text" name="entryid" value="" placeholder="Enter valid id" style="height:30px; text-align: center"/>
</div> 
<div class="centerize" style="height:20px"></div>
<div class="centerize">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height: 30px; width: 100px"/>
</div> 
<div class="centerize">
   @Html.ValidationSummary()
</div>
```

Comment: @user..which validation you want? Java script validation ?

Comment: You can check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.100).aspx to get an idea. And this : http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/D8I4270712-MVC-Data-Annotations-for-Model-Validation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do want to use **Javascript** validation:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.userid,new {id="userid"})
```

**JS:**

```
$(#submit).click(function()
{
    var data=$("#userid").val();

     if(data.length==0)
     {
       alert("Please enter user id");
      return false;  
     }
});
```

If you want to use `data annotations` for your model for validation just use `[Required]` attribute for your

field `userid`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do it on server side, add a Required data Annotation to the field:

```
[Required]
public string UserId{get;set;}
```

And, if you wanna do it on client-side, use this script;

```
<script>
$('input:submit').click(function()
{
    var $entryId=$('input[name="entryid"]').val();    
     if($entryId.trim()=="")
     {
       alert("Entry Id is required!");
      return false;  
     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: <div class="centerize"><input type="text" name="entryid" value="" placeholder="Enter valid id" style="height:30px; text-align: center"/></div>
     <div class="centerize" style="height:20px"></div>
<div class="centerize"><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height: 30px; width: 100px"/></div>
     <div class="centerize">@Html.ValidationSummary()</div>

Comment: when I click on button without enter id in textbox error message is not displayed. Please check my code

Comment: do you want to do it on client?